# How to make PHP error when using an non-integer key for array-accessing a string

Tags: php, arrays, casting, error-handling

In PHP, you can access characters in a string with the array syntax:

```
$foo = 'abc';
echo $foo[2]; // echos 'c'
```

I recently spent way too long debugging why `$foo['id']` wasn't giving me the expected result. It turned out that `$foo` was a string instead of an associative array. PHP seemed to be casting `'id'` to the integer `0`, without giving any notice:

```
$foo = 'abc';
echo $foo['id']; // echos 'a', without notice
```

PHP throws a nice warning when you do this with real arrays:

```
$foo = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$echo $foo['id']; // Notice:  Undefined index: id in php shell code on line 1
```

How can I make (or why can't) PHP throw an "Undefined index" notice instead of casting a string index to 0?

Comment: [Not even in strict mode! Stupid thing.](http://codepad.org/PK3Ndn1f)

Comment: Is there any static analysis tool that might catch this?

Comment: I think that'd be a good second question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do, short of patching PHP.

However, if you do want to patch PHP, this is a possible patch (against trunk):

```
Index: Zend/zend_execute.c
===================================================================
--- Zend/zend_execute.c (revision 316974)
+++ Zend/zend_execute.c (working copy)
@@ -1268,7 +1268,7 @@
                                                case IS_DOUBLE:
                                                case IS_NULL:
                                                case IS_BOOL:
-                                                       /* do nothing */
+                                                       zend_error(E_NOTICE, "String offset is not an integer");
                                                        break;
                                                default:
                                                        zend_error(E_WARNING, "Illegal offset type");
```

Then:

```
$ ~/php/php-t/bin/php -d error_reporting=-1 -r '$a="foo"; echo $a["bar"];'

Notice: String offset is not an integer in Command line code on line 1
f
```

Comment: Submitting this as a bug report might not hurt either.

Comment: @Shadikka: Enhancement request*

Comment: @Sha It was just an example, it would have to more a little smarter, for instance to give no notice on numeric strings like "6". But than wouldn't be very difficult (there are already functions for that).

Comment: @dave1010: Nooo do not patch PHP. What a portability/compatibility/documentation nightmare that would be.

Comment: @Tom If it's just for catching bugs in development, there's no big issue. It's like loading Xdebug.

Comment: @Artefacto: As long as the programmer remains very aware that instances of this new error are to be removed, not relied upon. And it's still a maintenance nightmare as you have to keep re-applying the patch every single time you upgrade.

Comment: I'm not actually going to patch PHP, but it's the only actual answer that works and it's led me to learn more about PHP.

Answer (score 0):

because [0] is ALWAYS the first character, if it's a string. You can check array with

```
if (is_array($array_or_string)){
    //it's an arra
}
```

Comment: I stuck in some type hinting (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) to check.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a "feature"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr):

> Writing to an out of range offset pads the string with spaces.
>   **Non-integer types are converted to integer.** Illegal offset type emits
>   E_NOTICE. Negative offset emits E_NOTICE in write but reads empty
>   string. Only the first character of an assigned string is used.
>   Assigning empty string assigns NULL byte.

And [the string `'id'` converts to integer zero](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. **If the string
>   starts with valid numeric data,** this will be the value used.
>   **Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).** Valid numeric data is an
>   optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a
>   decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an
>   'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.

You can't change this. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.4 now shows an error!

```
$foo = 'abc';
echo $foo['id'];
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'id' in php shell code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0
```